# secAst lib prerequisites too new for Debian/Utuntu 12 LTS?

Tags: asterisk, security

as requested in FAQ I wrote here the question (there is no question for this product yet on this site?)

This Asterisk securing tool looks very nice so I tried to test it out:
         http://www.generationd.com/Pages/Products/SECAST.php

But I just stumble over the setup part although the package should be usable with Ubuntu 12 LTS:

```
root@pbx~$ ldd secast-0.345.3.0-x86_64-ub12/secast
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffffbded000)
    libQt5Sql.so.5 => not found
    libQt5Xml.so.5 => not found
    libQt5Network.so.5 => not found
    libQt5Core.so.5 => not found
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ff6b71c4000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007ff6b6ec3000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007ff6b6cad000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff6b68ed000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff6b73ef000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007ff6b65f0000)
root@pbx~$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS
root@pbx~$ aptitude search libQt5
root@pbx~$ aptitude search libQt4 | wc -l
80
```

Ubuntu 12 LTS and Debian Squeeze/Wheezy have all only libQt4 but no libQt5 installed...

=> is there a chance to get additional package offer for this libQt version?

Bests

Reiner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to add the Qt5 package to your Ubuntu installation.  The exact steps are provided in section 5.1 of the installation guide but I'll repeat them here for convenience:

```
apt-get install software-properties-common
apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk
```

This will add a repo for you containing the Qt5 packages for your Ubuntu distro.

And for your other question, we did recently stop running our own forums (too much work dealing with spammers) for the free (community) edition and rely on serverfault or distro specific forums.

Please note that the link should be [www.telium.io](https://www.telium.io) as the company rebranded.

Comment: Thx... then it would be nice if further documentations can get in topic 2.6 a hint that further Informations can be found in topic 5. ;)

Comment: DONE!  We put a not cautioning the reader to check section 5 before proceeding.